# A Split Function to Extract the String 'go'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table-valued function called Split. The function takes 2 strings. It will split the 1st string into rows based on the value of the 2nd string.

I want to the function to split sql on the 'go' statements. The problem is that it will split the sql string when it finds the string 'go' anywhere in the sql. I need it to split on the string 'go' only when it is on a line all by itself. Any ideas? I am hoping not to have to re-write the function but to modify it in some (hopefully simple) way.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE
        type = 'TF' AND name = 'Split')
  BEGIN
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
  END
GO 

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split
(
    @RowData nvarchar(MAX),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(50)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
Id int identity(1,1),
Data nvarchar(MAX)
) 
AS  
BEGIN 
Declare @Cnt int
DECLARE @tst varchar(MAX)

Set @Cnt = 1

While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)
Begin
    Select 
        @tst =     ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)));

    Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
    Select 
        Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))

    Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+2,len(@RowData))
    Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
End

Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))

Return
END
GO

-- test out the function
SELECT data 
        FROM dbo.Split('
begin transaction;
go

alter table activity_log add
  hcm_got_estimate_num char(16) default (NULL);
go

set ANSI_NULLS on;
go

commit;
go'
, 'go');
```

Comment: You need to split on `<end of line>go<end of line>`.  I'm not sure how this is represented in your data, but it often involves combinations of ASCII characters 10 and 13 (carriage return and linefeed).

Comment: "When it is on a line by itself"? Wouldn't it have a **space** in front and back? Wouldn't it have a length as itself?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to add carriage return to the 'go' in "split-on" parameter. Unfortunately split doesn't work very well on such combination (some artifacts remain). So in order not to mess with the Split function you can prep the text by replacing carriage return + 'go' with some special character and then do the split on that character:

```
SELECT data 
        FROM dbo.Split(REPLACE('
begin transaction;
go

alter table activity_log add
  hcm_got_estimate_num char(16) default (NULL);
go

set ANSI_NULLS on;
go

commit;
go',char(13) + char(10) + 'go', '¬')
,  '¬');
```